# Matching nearest values in two dataframes of different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matching

If I have two dataframes of different lengths, different labels and different levels of digit precision like so:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.array([1.2345,2.2345,3.2345]),'b':np.array([4.123,5.123,6.123])})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.array([1.2346,2.2343]),'B':np.array([4.1232,5.1239])})
```

How can I find the rows where the two dataframes have approximately matching values between columns 'a' and 'A' (say within 2 digits of precision) that results in a dataframe like so

```
      a         b         A         B
------------------------------------------------
 | 1.2345  |  4.123  |  1.2346  |  4.1232  |
 | 2.2345  |  5.123  |  2.2343  |  5.1239  |
```

Attempts:

Attempt #1:

```
matches_df = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='inner', left_on=['a'], right_on = ['A'])
```

This only works if there are exact matches between columns 'a' and 'A' but I'm not sure how to incorporate a fudge factor to allow matching rows that are within 2 digits of precision.

Attempt #2

```
matches_df = df1.loc[np.round(df1['a'],2)==np.round(df2['A'],2)]
```

This gives the error "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" because *I think* the two dataframes have different labels ('a','b' and 'A','B').

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491342/merging-pandas-dataframes-based-on-nearest-values

Comment: Thank you for showing me that link, unfortunately the pd.merge approach doesn't seem to work for me in that way I want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html), you can find the closest math in `df1` in `m O(log n)` which `n` is the number of elements in `df2` and `m` number of elements in `df1`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.array([1.2345,2.2345,3.2345]),'b':np.array([4.123,5.123,6.123])})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.array([1.2346,2.2343]),'B':np.array([4.1232,5.1239])})


def spatial_merge_NN(df1, df2, xyz=['A', 'B']):
    ''' Add features from df2 to df1, taking closest point '''
    tree = cKDTree(df2[xyz].values)
    dists, indices = tree.query(df1[['a','b']].values, k=1)
    fts = [c for c in df2.columns]
    for c in fts:
        df1[c] = df2[c].values[indices]
    return df1

df_new = spatial_merge_NN(df1, df2, ['A', 'B'])
#         a      b       A       B
# 0  1.2345  4.123  1.2346  4.1232
# 1  2.2345  5.123  2.2343  5.1239
# 2  3.2345  6.123  2.2343  5.1239
```

It put one dataframe constant ( in this case `df1`) and iterate through `df2` and find the closest pair from `d2` and add that row.

Comment: Thank you! This approach seems to just return df1 without the matching data from df2. Looking at the function, it's not clear how to request a specific precision of digits to get matching rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is great. In the 'A','B' columns, there seems to be a duplicate row. I think this may always be the case so I added a new line before return df1 to remove the last row: df1.drop(df1.tail(1).index,inplace=True). 

While that works in this case, do you have any idea how I could alter the digit precision for matching rows with this method, to make this a more general answer?  Would it be the "leafsize" argument in the cKDTree function?

Comment: @DaxFeliz Yes. The way it works is it put one dataframe constant ( in this case df1) and iterate through `df2` and find the closest pair from `d2` and add that row. That means, you might expect to see duplications in `df2` data. You may consider removing duplicate rows